# Be of the size of or be the size of

Tags: prepositions, syntax

Tell me please which of the following sentences is correct.

1. "The planet is **of** the size of the earth."
2. "The planet is the size of the earth."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are grammatucal.  But the use of the first preposition of is old-fashioned in modern English.  So the second sentence as follows is far more common and idiomatic:

The planet is the size of (the same size as) the earth.